# C++ if 'something' isn't null AND isn't "0.0.0.0"

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me with the code below?

```
if(pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String != "" && pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String != "0.0.0.0");
      {
        printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);
      }
```

Is this wrong? I'm new to C++. All i want is to print the result only if `pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String` ISN'T NULL and also NOT "0.0.0.0".

Thank you!

Comment: In C, you need to use `strcmp`.  Not sure about C++.

Comment: what is the type of `String`? `std::string`?

Comment: What is the type of `pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String`. Also, `!= ""` checks if something is not equals to empty string literal, not null. To check if something is not null you neet to do `!= 0` (old syntax) or in c++11 `!= nullptr`

Comment: In his case, string can't really be null

Comment: @Gasim, Depends on what type `String` has. It could be a `char *`  for all we know.

Comment: *If* the `String` member is of type `std::string`, then it can't be null (in the sense of a null pointer), but it can be empty. If it's a `char*`, then the `!=` comparisons are legal but useless; they check whether it has the identical address to the location used to store the string literal. The question is unanswerable without knowing how the `String` member is defined. (Don't confuse `NULL`, a null *pointer* constant, with `""` a null (i.e., empty) *string* -- or with `'\0'` the null *character*).

Comment: if its `std::string`, I wouldn't test string against an empty string but check its size `!string.empty()`

Comment: Since it's passed to `printf` as `%s` it's probably `(const) char*` but you never know :>

Answer (score 8):

There are several potential issues here.

- NULL, aka 0, aka the "null pointer", is *not* the same thing as the empty string, `""`.  Depending on larger context, you may want to check for one or the other or both.
- Comparing C-style strings (better thought of as arrays of small integers, those small integers usually, but not necessarily, corresponding to code points in some encoding of text) with `==` or `!=` is silently accepted, but does not do what you expect; it compares the *memory addresses of the arrays*, not their contents.  "String literal" syntax in C++ produces anonymous instances of these arrays.
- C++ `std::string` objects are much more like first-class string objects in higher-level languages, and applying `==` or `!=` to them *does* compare their contents.  And writing `str == "literal"` etc. [*does* compare the contents of the string to the contents of the literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).  However, these objects cannot be passed directly to `printf`.

You have not told us which of the two you have (or whether it is something else again, such as an application-specific string class) so I am only speculating, but you *probably* want either

```
char const *gw_name = pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String;
if (gw_name       // checks for NULL - remove if impossible
    && *gw_name   // idiomatic shorthand check for "" - remove if impossible
    && strcmp(gw_name, "0.0.0.0")) // strcmp returns 0 if equal,
                                   // 1 or -1 if unequal
  printf("\tGateway:\t%s\n", gw_name);
```

or

```
std::string const &gw_name = pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String;
// gw_name cannot be NULL in this case
if (!gw_name.empty() && gw_name != "0.0.0.0")
  printf("\tGateway\t%s\n", gw_name.c_str());
```

depending on whether `pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String` is a C-style string or a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the following way

```
if ( !pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String.empty() &&  pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String != "0.0.0.0" );
      {
        printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String.c_str() );
      }
```

provided that pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String has type std::string.

Otherwise if pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String has type char [] or char * then I would wriye

```
if ( pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String[0] != '\0' && strcmp( pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String, "0.0.0.0" ) != 0 )
      {
        printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String );
      }
```

Comment: It is wrong to change the OP's code formatting, but it is also wrong to propagate egregious mis-formatting into your answers.  Answers should demonstrate good style as well as good practice.  In this case, you should not put a space after an open parenthesis or before a close parenthesis (and you *especially* should not put a space in one place but not the other) and block braces should not be indented relative to the 'if'.

Comment: I still get `Gateway:        0.0.0.0` i will try with @Zack 's way..! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way

```
  if (stricmp(pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String, "0.0.0.0") != 0 )
  //if(pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String != "0.0.0.0");
  {
    printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);
  }
```

Thank you for your support!!!

Comment: There is no standard C library function named `stricmp`.  In the land of nonstandardized legacy APIs, where that function exists, given this particular input it *should* do the exact same thing as `strcmp`.  Did `strcmp` not work for you?